# How to send a HTML code with session$sendCustomMessage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, shinydashboard

First, you will highlight the function you want to send to `JS` with `sendCustomMessage`:

```
fx <- function(x) {

  if (x <= 33) {
  
    "<p style='color:black;background-color:white;'>Hello</p>"
  
  } else if (x <= 66) {
  
    "<p style='color:yellow;background-color:red;'>World</p>"
  
  } else ("<p style='color:orange;background-color:green;'>!</p>")

}
```

I will also highlight the custom message:

```
session$sendCustomMessage(
  type = "box1", 
  list(
    text = fx(
      x = pred_1()
      )
    )
  )
```

My shinyApp:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  
  title = "Dashboard", 
  titleWidth = 300
  
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  width = 300
  
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "s1", 
    label = "S1", 
    value = 5, 
    min = 1, 
    max = 100, 
    step = 1
  ), 
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "s2", 
    label = "S2", 
    value = 5, 
    min = 1, 
    max = 100, 
    step = 1
  ), 
  
  box(
    id = "g1", title = "My gauge", background = "black", status = "warning", 
    width = 6, collapsible = T, collapsed = F, 
    footer = "This is my first gauge", 
    flexdashboard::gaugeOutput(
    outputId = "value1"
    )
  )
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  header = header, sidebar = sidebar, body = body, skin = "red"
  
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  fsum <- function(x, y) {
    
    x + y
    
  }
  
  fx <- function(x) {
    
      if (x <= 33) {
      
      "<p style='color:black;background-color:white;'>Hello</p>"
      
    } else if (x <= 66) {
      
      "<p style='color:yellow;background-color:red;'>World</p>"
      
    } else ("<p style='color:orange;background-color:green;'>!</p>")
    
  }
  
  reac_0 <- reactive({
    
    tibble::tibble(
      s1 = input$s1,
      s2 = input$s2
      )
    
  })
  
  pred_1 <- reactive({
    
    temp <- reac_0()
    fsum(
      x = temp$s1, 
      y = temp$s2
    )
    
  })
  
  output$value1 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      type = "box1", 
      list(
        text = fx(
          x = pred_1()
          )
        )
      )
    
    expr = flexdashboard::gauge(
      value = pred_1(), min = 1, max = 100, symbol = " +", 
      flexdashboard::gaugeSectors(
        c(1, 33), c(34, 66), c(67, 1000), colors = c("red", "orange", "green")
      ), 
      label = ""
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Inside `.js` file, I insert this code:

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(
  type = "box1",
  data => $("#value1.html-widget.gauge svg text[font-size='10px'] 
  tspan:eq(0)").html(data.text)
  );
```

To style the gauge label. But, doesn't work.

On the other hand, when I replace `fx` with `fy` (text only):

```
  fy <- function(x) {

    if (x <= 70) {
  
      "Hello"
  
    } else if (x <= 100) {
  
      "World"
  
    } else ("!")

  }
```

Works fine.

**Edit**

I tried add `URLencode` in `if` structure:

```
  fx <- function(x) {

    if (x <= 70) {
  
      URLencode("<p style='color:black;background-color:white;'>Hello</p>")
  
    } else if (x <= 100) {
  
      URLencode("<p style='color:yellow;background-color:red;'>World</p>")
  
    } else (URLencode("<p style='color:orange;background-color:green;'>!</p>"))

  }
```

And `decodeURI` in `.js` file:

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(
  type = "box1",
  data => $("#value1.html-widget.gauge svg text[font-size='10px'] 
  tspan:eq(0)").html(decodeURI(data.text))
  );
```

But, doesn't work.

So how to pass an `HTML` from `R` to `JavaScript`/ `jQuery` with `sendCustomMessage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode the html on the R side with `URLencode` and decode it on the Javascript side with `decodeURI`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do what you said, but I couldn't get it to work. I believe I don't know how to adjust the `decodeURI` in the `.js` file. See my edited answer.

Comment: @neves Oh, this is some svg. I don't know whether the `p` tag works in `svg`. Did you try `tspan` instead of `p`?

Comment: It works for the label, but the colors don't change.

Comment: @neves a lot of standard HTML stuff does not work in SVG. But I'm not a SVG master, I can't help you more, sorry.

Comment: I've identified the problem, I'm grateful for the help. Greetings.